# Como usar CHARSET corretamente no AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

eu estou iniciando em Angular e estou com uma dúvida básica.. Quando passo dados de um formulário para outra tela de apresentação, os caracteres com acentuação estão sendo apresentados todos bagunçados. Por favor me ajudem a identificar o porque o script abaixo não está funcionando.

```html
  var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=iso-8859-1'
                }
            }
    $http.post('views/protected/apresenta_result.php', data, config)
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
          {
     sucesso();
          })
          .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
          {
              console.log('error');
     erro();
          });
```

Answer (score 2):

Voce precisa definir um Accept no cabeçalho.

```
Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
```

```
    var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Accept': "application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    'Accept-Charset':"charset=utf-8',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=iso-8859-1'
                }
            }
                $http.post('views/protected/apresenta_result.php', data, config)
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
                {
                    sucesso();
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
                {
                    console.log('error');
                    erro();
                });
```